# Finding number of basic solution based on different cases

Tags: linear-programming

I need help understanding the question.

Consider the polyhedron P = {x in R^n | Ax = b x => 0}, where
A in R^mxn and b in R^m. Assume that any m columns of A are linearly independent.

(a) Suppose all the basic solutions are nondegenerate. Express the number of basic solutions in terms of m choose n

(b) Suppose that k basic solutions are degenerate, and each of these degenerate solutions
have n+1 active constraints. Furthermore, all other basic solutions are nondegenerate.
How many basic solutions are there?

(c) Suppose that there is one basic solution that is degenerate, and has n + 2 active
constraints. Furthermore, all other basic solutions are nondegenerate. How many
basic solutions are there?

for (a), I'm not sure if it is 2m choose n since there are 2m constraints and we need to ensure that there are n constraints to be tight.

Hope someone can enlighten me!

Thanks!